# Tabs do not work when rendering from terminal

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am rendering an Rmd website from terminal. Say, I have files *index.Rmd* and *_site.yml*

*index.Rmd*

```
---
title: Home
---

# Title {.tabset .tabset-fade}

## Subtitle 1

Some content

## Subtitle 2

Some more content

#
```

*_site.yml*

```
name: RMD test
navbar:
  title: RMD test
  right:
    - text: Home
      href: index.html
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document
```

If I run `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site()"` or `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('index.Rmd')"`, the tabs are not rendered correctly in the output html. I have also tried running it in the absence of **_site.yml**, but that doesn't help either.

[image]

But, if I run within RStudio, `rmarkdown::render("index.Rmd")`, `rmarkdown::render_site()` or click 'Knit', the tabs render correctly.

[image]

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
rmarkdown 1.17
markdown 1.1
knitr 1.26
pandoc 2.8.1
```

Comment: `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site()"` and `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('index.Rmd')"` both worked fine for me to generate the tabs. I'm using R 3.6.1, macOS Catalina 10.15.2, pandoc 2.4, rmarkdown 1.18, knitr 1.26, and Google Chrome 79.0.3945.117 (also worked fine in Firefox 70.0).

Comment: Yep! I just tried it on R 3.6.1 and everything works as expected.